# Sass always throw errors to a correct maps

Tags: sass

this is my maps

```
$breakpoints: (
  'xs' : ( max-width: 600px ),
  'sm' : ( min-width: 600px and max-width: 960px ),
  'md' : ( min-width: 960px and max-width: 1264px ),
  'lg' : ( min-width: 1264px and max-width: 1904px ),
  'xl' : ( min-width: 1904px )
);
```

And this is what the console print

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):                                                                    friendly-errors 19:52:50
SassError: expected ")".
  ╷
5 │ $breakpoints: (
  │                ^
  ╵
  assets/style/main.sass 5:16  root stylesheet
```

I just don't know why the map is wrong ... I've replaced the map above with some example code, but it still can't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"()"-brackets indicate that the nested items indeed are nested maps, use quotation marks instead, to make it a string. You also used `sm` twice. Duplicate keys will always throw an error.

```
$breakpoints: (
  "xs": "(max-width: 600px)",
  "sm": "(min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 960px)",
  "md": "(min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1264px)",
  "lg": "(min-width: 1264px) and (max-width: 1904px)",
  "xl": "(min-width: 1904px)",
);
```

I also wrapped each of the media feature in its own set of brackets, to make it the valid syntax.

You can use this now as:

```
@each $key, $value in $breakpoints {
   @media #{$value} {
      // ...
   }
}
```

To recieve:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  //...
}

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  //...
}

//...
```

Comment: But it can't work correctly either...the console still print error above

Comment: @Hydrostatic, then it's maybe the way you try to use it. I updated my answer.

Comment: I change it into single line and it doesn't throw errors